# Run-Time-Error 1004 when adding Data Validation

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to add a Dropdown-List in a protected document.

The code I am using is:

```
Private Sub AddDropDown_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    Dim currCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For Each currCell In Range("K4:K" & lastRow)
        With currCell.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIREKT(J" & currCell.Row & ")"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    Next currCell
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

But when I try to run the code it throws an Error 1004 in the row the .Add is excecuted.

Most of the parameters throw the same Error when I try whatching them while debugging:

[image: Debug Screenshot Validation]

Does anyone have an idea what causes this?

Comment: First, you need to qualify your `formula` with the range, so it need to be `cell.formula <> ""` .Second, what is `"INDIREKt"` ? are you using German settings of Excel ?

Comment: Where is your `Formula` variable set? (`If formula <> "" Then`) Don't you mean `Cell.Formula`? Secondly, you're using a German version of your "indirect" formula in your code - Try English.

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes I have the German Excel-Version as you can also see in the screenshot. The formula was a part I had in there before changing some things. Removed it from question.

Comment: @ShaiRado not even... posted it and then saw yours standing there... Let's stick to "great minds think alike"

Answer (score 0):

The German formula is OK. But try following these points to debug:

1. Remove on Error resume next
2. Rename `cell` to anything else. E.g. `myCell` or `rngCell`.
3. Put `debug.print lastRow` before `For Each cell In Range("K4:K" & lastRow)`.
4. Put `Option Explicit` on the top and try to compile the code.

Comment: Did all that and changed it in the Question. Still does not work. "On Error" also did not work. I still got the Error-Message. And "lastRow" is 2214 whitch is correct.